# Conflict with SVN: svn/me

Tags: svn

All SVN posts I have found to do with `!svn/me` talk about `!svn/me' forbidden`, but that isn't what I am seeing. I am not sure where to start, since `!svn/me` is obviously a special folder of some sort..

```
$ svn commit .
svn: E160024: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E160024: '/svn/my_repo/!svn/me' conflicts
svn: E160024: Your commit message was left in a temporary file:
svn: E160024:    '/c/Users/robert.bram/my_repo/svn-commit.2.tmp'
```

I have tried `svn update`, `svn cleanup`, neither of which got rid of the issue.

### Update

Unfortunately there is no technical fix here. I was using a free account on a source control system provider,  and they have stopped their free accounts, thus I can no longer commit. (I confirmed this with the provider.)

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the `/!svn/me` part which if I am not mistaken has a special meaning and simply refers to the root of the repository. The main error here is `conflicts`. So do you have conflicts in your working copy? Do you maybe have property conflicts? You need to double-check that, resolve the conflicts and then commit.

Comment: No conflicts at all: `svn st | grep '^C'`

Comment: I checked out the repo to another directory.. (nice and fresh) made a change, and found the same error.

Comment: @RobertMarkBram what's your server and client version? What's in the server log?

Comment: I have been using a free `unfuddle` account. Looks like they are not doing that anymore and are cutting me off. Looks like I need to find a new host.

Comment: Thanks for the help @bahrep, I got confirmation that I can no longer commit without paying, thus there is no technical fix here.

Comment: @RobertMarkBram oh, that's unfortunate. Have you considered hosting your own server? Try VisualSVN Server https://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/